# Unable to use .strip() in a multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, strip

I have a multidimensional list with a layout like this

```
[['Company Name      ', ['companyemail@email.com']]
['Company Name   ', ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']]
['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']]
['Company Name          ', ['companyemail@email.com']]]
```

I need to remove the white spaces before and after the names in the first index in every item.

I have already tried this:

```
def name_filter(vendors):
    unfiltered=vendors
    filtered=[]
    count=0
    for i in unfiltered:
        filtered = [x.strip(' ') for x in unfiltered[count][0]]
        count+=1
    return filtered
```

However when I print the list it doesn't display anything except one letter

My expected outcome is:

```
[['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']]
['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']]
['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']]
['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']]]
```

Comment: Actually you have 4 lists here no?

Comment: @SebastienD sorry i changed it.

Comment: your list is a syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this recursively - strip each element if it's a string, or recur if it's a list:

```
def recursive_strip(lst):
    return [(elem.strip() if type(elem) == str else recursive_strip(elem)) for elem in lst]
```

You may need to make allowances for what datatypes the list can contain (the above assumes only strings or lists).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a for loop over the first item of each list and then stripping white spaces. As a result, you are getting individual characters. You do not need **a second for loop inside the list comprehension**. Just strip the first string element and append the second simultaneously. P.S: I also defined the nested list `vendors` as input because I assume that this is your correct input structure based on your logic of the code

```
vendors = [['Company Name      ', ['companyemail@email.com']],
           ['Company Name   ', 
           ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']],
           ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']],
           ['Company Name          ', ['companyemail@email.com']]]

def name_filter(vendors):
    unfiltered=vendors
    filtered=[]
    for i in unfiltered:
        print (i)
        filtered.append([i[0].strip(' '), i[1]]) # <--- This is the key line

    return filtered

name_filter(vendors)

# [['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']],
#  ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com', 'companyemail@email.com']],
#  ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']],
#  ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it inside a list comprehension:

```
vendors = [['Company Name      ', ['companyemail@email.com']],
           ['Company Name   ', ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']],
           ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']],
           ['Company Name          ', ['companyemail@email.com']]]

vendors = [ [company[0].strip(),*company[1:]] for company in vendors ]
```

Each item in vendors being a list itself, you need to output a list with the first item stripped in the comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [str.rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

```
vendors = \
    [['Company Name      ', ['companyemail@email.com']],
    ['Company Name   ', ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']],
    ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']],
    ['Company Name          ', ['companyemail@email.com']]]


filtered_vendors = [[vendor[0].rstrip(),vendor[1]] for vendor in vendors]
```

Comment: Why not use tuple unpacking?

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot commas

```
unfiltered = [['Company Name      ', ['companyemail@email.com']], ['Company Name   ', ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']], ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']] ,['Company Name          ', ['companyemail@email.com']]]
filtered = []
count=0
text = ''
for i in unfiltered:
    print(i[0])
    test = str((i[0])).strip()
    filtered.append( (str(i)).replace(i[0],test))


print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
unfiltered = [['Company Name      ', ['companyemail@email.com']], ['Company Name   ', ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']], ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']] ,['Company Name          ', ['companyemail@email.com']]]
filtered = []
count=0
text = ''
for i in unfiltered:
    print(i[0])
    test = str((i[0])).strip()
    filtered.append( (str(i)).replace(i[0],test))


print(filtered)


unfiltered = [['Company Name      ', ['companyemail@email.com']], ['Company Name   ', ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']], ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']] ,['Company Name          ', ['companyemail@email.com']]]
filtered = []
print(unfiltered)
count=0
text = ''
for i in unfiltered:
    print(i[0])
    test = str((i[0])).strip()
    filtered.append( (str(i)).replace(i[0],test))


print(filtered)
[['Company Name      ', ['companyemail@email.com']], ['Company Name   ', ['companyemail@email.com', 'companyemail@email.com']], ['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']], ['Company Name          ', ['companyemail@email.com']]]
Company Name      
Company Name   
Company Name
Company Name          
["['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']]", "['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com', 'companyemail@email.com']]", "['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']]", "['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']]"]
>>>
```